# Point a Python Turtle towards certain coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Is there any way to point the Turtle towards certain coordinates

Any help with this with be appreciated.

Comment: turtle.setheading(math.degrees(math.atan2(target_pos - current_pos)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `turtle.towards()` method, which returns the angle from the turtle's position to a target.  It can be used in combination with the `turtle.setheading()` method:

```
turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x, y))
```

The `turtle.towards()` method is flexible with respect to it arguments. It can take separate `x` and `y` values, a combined `(x, y)` tuple, or another turtle whose position it will target.

It's a commonly overlooked method, that folks reimplement, along with `turtle.distance()`.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments, you can use a bit of trigonometry to head to a specific point:

```
target = (100,50)
d = math.degrees(math.atan2(*(target - turtle.pos())))
turtle.setheading(d)
```